# Encode/Decode SHA256WITHECDSA - nodeJS

Tags: java, node.js

I'm trying to decode/encode a signature with SHA256withECDSA.
I have a Java code that works fine:

```
public void verify() throws Exception {
    Signature ecdsaVerify = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA"));
    EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode("your public key goes here"));
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
    ecdsaVerify.initVerify(publicKey);

    ecdsaVerify.update("All the webhook field values (only the values) concatenated together using a semicolon ;".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    boolean result = ecdsaVerify.verify(Base64.getDecoder().decode("Signature to verify")); //Must return true
}
```

but I need this solution for nodejs.
when I'm creating an base64 buffer in nodejs it's getting a different results from the Java code.
I currently use cryptojs & jwa npm's.

Edit:

this is my code for nodejs:

```
var jwa = require("jwa");

const verifySignature = () => {
let public_key = Buffer.from("public key here", "base64");
let signature = Buffer.from("Signature_here", "base64");
let payload = "data here seperated by semicolon";
let ecdsa = jwa("ES256");
let verify = ecdsa.verify(payload, signature, public_key);
}
verifySignature();
```

Comment: Would you be able to share your Node.js code so we can debug the code in question please

Comment: yeah, I share it now

Answer (score 0):

JWA implements the algorithms used in JOSE, and in particular for ECDSA uses the signature format (aka encoding) defined in P1363 that simply contains fixed-length R and S concatenated; see steps 2 and 3 of https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-3.4 . This is not the format used by most other standards, and in particular by Java, which is an ASN.1 DER-encoded SEQUENCE of two INTEGER values, which are (both) variable length (all) with tag and length prefixes.

You don't need JWA at all; builtin 'crypto' has the functionality you need:

```
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class SO70655734 {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "some;test;data";
    String pubkey = "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEyOFORyCVCxX+W4QZevzH6skTbp2lVDtRLV0+7ypHjX26wFtSWSe4MTI0GZjIKDOAIT8KpbqH8HXI6Wo5S6/6hg==";
    String sig = "MEQCICDLwztlKOXmQLuDJ0Hh96gGAT2/wsm2ymw3CDxSDnB3AiAK7eR8+C6g/zw5TmXUX0K/pV5kjIJTCieIkQXzH30WYA==";

    Signature ecdsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
    ecdsa.initVerify(KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePublic(
      new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(pubkey)) ));
    ecdsa.update(data.getBytes("UTF-8")); // or StandardCharsets.UTF_8 
    System.out.println(ecdsa.verify(Base64.getDecoder().decode(sig)));
  }
}
-> true

const crypto = require('crypto');

const data = "some;test;data";
const pubkey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
  + "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEyOFORyCVCxX+W4QZevzH6skTbp2lVDtRLV0+7ypHjX26wFtSWSe4MTI0GZjIKDOAIT8KpbqH8HXI6Wo5S6/6hg==\n"
  + "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
const sig = "MEQCICDLwztlKOXmQLuDJ0Hh96gGAT2/wsm2ymw3CDxSDnB3AiAK7eR8+C6g/zw5TmXUX0K/pV5kjIJTCieIkQXzH30WYA==";

var ecdsa = crypto.createVerify('SHA256');
ecdsa.update(data,'utf8');
console.log( ecdsa.verify(pubkey, sig,'base64') );
-> true
```

Note: recent versions of nodejs can instead take DER-format pubkey (without the BEGIN/END lines added, but with the base64 converted to binary), but my most convenient test system only has 8.10.0 so I went the more compatible old way.